PostgreSQL retention and partitions
I have two tables:
CREATE TABLE order (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    total NUMERIC(10, 2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE order_item (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    order_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES order(id),
    product_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES product(id),
    quantity INTEGER NOT NULL,
    price NUMERIC(10, 2) NOT NULL
);

I would like to partition these tables into two parts: order_current
for orders created within the last 12 months, and order_archive for orders older than 12 months.
How can I achieve this? Additionally, should the order_item table also be partitioned?
Thank you!
I was tring to find a solution using pg_partman, but could not find.

This question needs to be more focused. To that end read Table Partitioning, in particular sections 5.11.2. Declarative Partitioning and 5.11.6. Best Practices for Declarative Partitioning. Also this I was tring to find a solution using pg_partman, but could not find. is basically content free.

Why do you want to partition this table? What problem should it solve? "current" is something that changes all the time, you really don't want to move data around all the time. Waste of resources.

Table contains millions of records, most of the time only the current (last 12months) needs to be accessed

That is imho not a lot, and not a reason for partitioning. Do you have a performance problem? If so, could you share the result from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for your slow queries? (and the queries themself, all in plain text).

You could create partitions per month, for the next 10 or 20 years or so, and you don't need pg_partman at all. Not sure if this solves any problem, but it's something you could do.
